# c# text box "between" validation

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox

I am trying to have a text box validate if the entry is a number between 1 and 100.

Example:

```
if (textBox.Text is equal to numbers between 1 and 100)
{
    do this; 
} 
else 
{ 
    do this; 
}
```

This is form validation for a trackbar used for jpeg compression and can only have numeric values between 1 and 100. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: what's the technology you're using? WebForms, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms.

Comment: I'd check to see if you can set the minimum and maximum values for the trackbar in it's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String text = TextBox.Text;
try{
    long value = long.parse(text.trim());
    if(value > 0 && value < 101){
       //do something here
    }
    else{
       //Do something else
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
   Messagebox.Show("Please check you input and try again");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert input from textbox from string to integer

```
string textBoxvalue = textBox.Text;
int textBoxIntValue = int.TryParse(textBoxvalue)
```

then you need to check values for condition you need

```
if(textBoxIntValue > 0 && textBoxIntValue <= 100)
{
//do THIS
}
```